# Vue.js sync input field

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my vue application I've got lots and lots of input fields (example):

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="name" class="label">Naam</label>

    <div class="control">
        <input id="name"
               name="name"
               type="text"
               v-model="relation.name"
               class="input"
               :class="{ 'is-danger': errorsHas('name') }"
               autofocus>

        <p class="help is-danger" v-if="errorsHas('name')">{{ error('name') }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I would like to wrap this in a `input` component. But since vue 1 the `.sync` method is gone so how would I do this? Firing events is not realy a solution I guess. Just wondering how to solve this?

I would like to have something like this:

```
<custom-input v-model=relation.name></custom-input>
```

And everything else (class name, autofocus etc...) must be handled in that component.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sync modifier was reintroduced in 2.3.0+, see [Vue Js Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier).

> In 2.3.0+ we re-introduced the .sync modifier for props, but this time it is just syntax sugar that automatically expands into an additional v-on listener:

The following `<comp :foo.sync="bar"></comp>` is expanded into:

```
<comp :foo="bar" @update:foo="val => bar = val"></comp>
```

For the child component to update foo‘s value, it needs to explicitly emit an event instead of mutating the prop:

```
this.$emit('update:foo', newValue)
```

You may see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8jq4upa/) as an example.

Comment: Just what I need! But when and where would I fire: `this.$emit('update:foo', newValue)` ?

Comment: @Jenssen In your example what is the property you are trying to update?

Comment: I'm trying to update `relation.name` in a parent component.

Comment: @Jenssen You can do `<custom-input :relationName.sync="name"></custom-input>`, define `relationName` as a prop in your component, and then on your method where you update `this.relationName = newVal` just trigger `this.$emit('update:relationName', newValue)`

Comment: On my comment above you are mutating the property directly, you should not do that.. I'm still booting up.. See example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8jq4upa/)

Comment: @Jenssen I've [expanded @enriqg9's fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8jq4upa/5/) to demonstrate how you can use `sync` to a component with an input. The component can use a settable computed  to handle the event emits, and the input can use `v-model` with that computed.

Comment: @RoyJ thankss was just figuring out how to do this with an input field!

Answer (score 0):

You may use [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props) to be more specific [dynamic props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Props).

Just set up a appropriate component which accepts a `prop` and reference to that `prop` in your components `v-model`.

Your component could look like this (adjusted example from [official site](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props)):

```
Vue.component('custom-input', {
  // declare the props
  props: ['message'],
  // just like data, the prop can be used inside templates
  // and is also made available in the vm as this.message
  template: '<input v-model="message">'
})
```

While your parent would use it like that:

```
<custom-input :message="parentMsg"></custom-input>
```

Comment: thanks. But then I get: `Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "name"`